# ArcMap aerial raster image exposure is off

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, mapwindow

I have some aerial raster images and I want to create tiles for web.
So I added images as layers in Arcmap and as the result some images were overexposed with different lightness.
For comparing I opened the same images on other software MapWindow GIS. On it those images were fine.
So my question is how to get the same result on ArcMap as it was on MapWindow.
Here is examples of imagery:
Arcmap:
 [image: Arcmap example]

And the same raster on MapWindow:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like ArcMap is applying a "Stretch" to your images.

In your raster layer properties, on the symbology tab, try adjusting through the Stretch drop-down options until you find one that looks right.  I suspect turning off the Stretch altogether (select None) will give you the closest to what you see in MapWindow.

You may also be able to apply statistics for the entire dataset or display extent which may balance the visible images yet still enhance them.

[image]

Comment: You were right! It works now like a charm, thanks! :)